# lvalue required as left operand of assignment in c

Tags: c

```
while((count++<n) && *s1++=*s2++);
  *s1='\0';
```

i ran this piece of code and got an error `lvalue required as left operand of assignment in c`

i was able to correct it

```
while((count++<n) && (*s1++=*s2++));
  *s1='\0';
```

this works fine but i have no idea why. i read other threads in stack overflow saying lvalue should be an assignable value and should not be a constant.i cannot relate it.
is it because `(expression)` has a value  and `expression` doesnot? i tried to check it with

```
int c=3;
  int b=2;
 // printf("%d\n",c==b);
  printf("%d\n",(c=b));
```

both gave the same result of 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the first piece of code doesn't compile is `&&` operator has higher precedence in C than `=`.

So the compiler reads this as `((count++<n) && *s1++) = *s2++`, or more generally `(A && B) = C`.

Comment: ok! you mean to that that the line is treated as (count++<n && *s1++)=*s2++